# Does MongoDB Atlas support Meteor's oplog tailing on its shared/free tier?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-oplog

Meteor supports [oplog tailing](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/oplog-observe-driver.md) on a MongoDB replica set for more efficient updates.

[MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) has a free/shared tier that provides a replica set, [with some limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/unsupported-commands/): specifically, that the oplog can only be queried by string namespaces. [This article](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/mongodb-atlas-setup) describes setting up Meteor on Atlas, but doesn't mention whether this works on the shared tiers or only on the dedicated tiers with full oplog support.

What oplog queries does Meteor need to work properly? Does MongoDB Atlas support Meteor's oplog tailing on its free/shared tiers?

Comment: Yes, I checked and it does work on the MongoDB Atlas free tier!